# Type change in rvalue reference

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference

May I know why this piece of code is valid.Thanks.

```
  double i=5;//int i=5 will invalidate this piece of code
    int && r1=i;
    std::cout<<r1<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Could you highlight the specific suspicious thing in the question body?

Comment: Because if it is int i=5 then it becomes invalid because the reference bound to a lvalue

Comment: Though not sure, I guess the reference binds to an rvalue which is the result of implicit conversion.

Comment: @Nicky yeah seems logical but I failed to find out the exact definition about this kind of type change.

Comment: @Nicky C Thanks man, now I totally agree with you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[dcl.init.ref]/1** A variable declared to be a `T&` or `T&&`, that is, "reference to type `T`" (8.3.2), shall be initialized by an object, or function, of type `T` or by an object that can be converted into a `T`.
>
> **[dcl.init.ref]/5** A reference to type "`cv1 T1`" is initialized by an expression of type "`cv2 T2`" as follows:
>
> ...
>
> (5.2.2.2) -- If `T1` is a non-class type, a temporary of type "`cv1 T1`" is created and copy-initialized (8.5) from the initializer expression. The reference is then bound to the temporary.

Comment: Thanks for the reference :-)